# How to show a count of values based on condition of another column in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query:

```
Select ID,Event_Name,MAX(Page_URL) as URL,MAX(Value) as Value from database
Group by ID,Event_Name
Order by Event_Name
```

Which outputs the following data:

| ID | Event_Name | URL | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EV1 | website/ | 500 |
| 11 | EV1 | website/ | 500 |
| 3 | EV2 | website/two | 500 |
| 4 | EV2 | website/two | 500 |
| 6 | EV2 | website/four | 500 |
| 8 | EV2 | website/six | 500 |
| 5 | EV3 | website/three | 500 |
| 7 | EV3 | website/five | 500 |
| 9 | EV3 | website/four | 500 |
| 2 | EV4 | website/one | 500 |
| 10 | EV4 | website/eight | 500 |
| 12 | EV4 | website/ | 500 |

However, I'd like to introduce a count column which will count all the instances of the URL in the query based on their Event_Name. I would like this to output like this:

| ID | Event_Name | URL | Value | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EV1 | website/ | 500 | 2 |
| 11 | EV1 | website/ | 500 | 2 |
| 3 | EV2 | website/two | 500 | 2 |
| 4 | EV2 | website/two | 500 | 2 |
| 6 | EV2 | website/four | 500 | 1 |
| 8 | EV2 | website/six | 500 | 1 |
| 5 | EV3 | website/three | 500 | 1 |
| 7 | EV3 | website/five | 500 | 1 |
| 9 | EV3 | website/four | 500 | 1 |
| 2 | EV4 | website/one | 500 | 1 |
| 10 | EV4 | website/eight | 500 | 1 |
| 12 | EV4 | website/ | 500 | 1 |

Hopefully someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding up a `COUNT` window function as follows:

```
WITH cte AS (
    Select ID,Event_Name,MAX(Page_URL) as URL,MAX(Value) as Value from database
    Group by ID,Event_Name
    Order by Event_Name
)
SELECT *, COUNT(URL) OVER(PARTITION BY Event_Name, URL) AS cnt
FROM cte
```

Comment: Hi @lemon .I've tested that but it seems to be counting the total number of instances of the event_name not the number of instances of that particular URL within that particular event_name.

Comment: I got a typo in the partition by, try now.

Comment: Brilliant that's done the job exactly as I had expected. Much appreciated!